# Getting a "application: not a procedure" error

Tags: scheme

the purpose of this code is to remove and return the first N part of a list X

```
{define (grab x n) 
   (cond
     [(< (len x) n) x]  
     [(> n 1)((car x) (grab(cdr x) (- n 1)))]
     [(= n 1)(car x)]
 )}
```

it currently just returns the above error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in your solution:

- In the second condition, you forgot to `cons` the current value - remember, we're recursively building a *list* as an answer, and we must use `cons` to do so
- The second and third conditions should use `0` and not `1`. Otherwise the procedure will fail when `n` equals zero
- The base case, when `n` equals zero, should return the empty list - otherwise the output list will not be properly constructed

With all the above fixes in place, the procedure will work:

```
(define (grab x n)
  (cond
    [(< (len x) n) x]
    [(> n 0) (cons (car x) (grab (cdr x) (- n 1)))]
    [(= n 0) '()]))
```

As a side note, you're basically implementing the [`take`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._take%29%29) procedure, if that's available in your interpreter (except that `take` will raise an error if `n` is greater than the lists' length):

```
(take '(1 2 3 4 5) 3)
=> '(1 2 3)
```